# How to override Bootstrap theme files in sub-theme

Tags: theming

I'm creating a sub-theme based off Bootstrap. I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010) and is working ok.

Now I want to override the `tpl` files in `theme/block`, `theme/system`, etc.

In my sub-theme I've created the folder structure mimicking the one on Bootstrap (at least for the ones I want to override), yet it seems my files are not being used.

How can I override the aforementioned files (preferably) using the same structure?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put those files in yourtheme/templates/ (no sub-folder) and a quick cache clear after that.

See **bootstrap_subtheme/templates/README.txt**:

> This folder is where you should place all your overriding template files. By
>   default, the Bootstrap base theme provides all the necessary template files in
>   various folders inside of sites/*/themes/bootstrap/theme. For example, the
>   page.tpl.php template file is located at
>   sites/*/themes/bootstrap/theme/system/page.tpl.php. To override any of these
>   files, copy them from the Bootstrap base theme and place them in here.